# Rest API or CLI to hide Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-devops-rest-api

How to hide Azure DevOps services like 'Boards', 'Repos', 'Artifacts' etc. using CLI or Rest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to hide Azure DevOps services like 'Boards', 'Repos', 'Artifacts' etc. using CLI or Rest API?

You could do it by the REST API. But there isn’t official public REST API to do it.
The workaround is using internal REST API (captured through Developer tool or F12):

For example:

**Request URI:**

```
PATCH dev.azure.com{Organization_name}/_apis/FeatureManagement/FeatureStates/host/project/{Project_id}/{feature-id}?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

```
{"featureId":"{feature-id}","scope":{"settingScope":"project","userScoped":false},"state":0}
```

Replace account,project-id and feature-id as appropriate. Here are the feature id’s for others:

```
ms.vss-build.pipelines  [Azure Pipelines]
ms.vss-test-web.test [Test Plans]
ms.vss-work.agile [Azure Boards]
ms.vss-code.version-control [Azure Repos]
ms.feed.feed [Azure Artifacts]
```

You could refer [this document](https://www.teapotcoder.com/post/vsts-disable-features-services-api/) for some more details.

Comment: does the URI still work, i am getting this error "The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'

Comment: Ok got it working the Request URI should be this instead of one you posted:

PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{Organization_name}/_apis/FeatureManagement/FeatureStates/host/project/{Project_id}/{feature-id}?api-version=4.1-preview.1

That url from teapot coder was helpful.

Comment: @sanjeev, Sorry, Sorry, I accidentally posted the wrong URL. I have changed it now, I hope this didn't cause you too much trouble.